# Count with joins

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have three tables:

***User***
ID

***ImportFile***
ID
reportingUser_id

***Activity***
ID
importFile_id
date

I'm searching for a query which answers the following question:
How many ImportFiles with activities in one month does every user uploaded.

For Example:
User
1
2

ImportFile
1, 1
2, 1
3, 2

Activity
1, 1, 01.01.2018
2, 1, 15.01.2018
3, 2, 02.01.2018
4, 3, 02.01.2018

Expected Result:
User.id, count(importFiles), trunc(date, 'MM')
1, 2, 01.01.2018
2, 1, 01.01.2018

My (incorrect) query:

```
SELECT user.id, count(a.importfile_id), trunc(a.date, 'MM') FROM activity a 
left join importfile imp on imp.id = a.importfile_id 
left join user on user.id = importfile.reportingUser_id
group by trunc(a.date, 'MM'), a.importFile_id, user.id
```

Comment: What is wrong with your query?

Comment: It counts the cross product of all joins. The first row of the result for the example  would be: 1, 3, 01.01.2018 and not  1, 2, 01.01.2018

Comment: @MiZi is your data accurate? Looking at your ImportFile table there's no entry for User 2 so the relationship with Activity would fail? However, the second row of your expected result does have valid counts for User 2. Am I missing something?

Comment: @vishnud oh, your right. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you just need to fix the `GROUP BY` and use `COUNT(DISTINCT)`:

```
SELECT u.id, count(distinct a.id),
       trunc(a.date, 'MM')
FROM user u join
     importfile i
     on u.id = i.reportingUser_id join
     activity a 
     on i.id = a.importfile_id 
GROUP BY trunc(a.date, 'MM'), u.id;
```

I changed the `JOIN`s.  Each activity should have proper import files and users, so outer joins don't seem necessary.

Answer (score 0):

I think your query needs to changes:
1.) count(distinct a.importfile_id) instead of count (a.importfile_id) as a file may have multiple activities
2) as what @Gordon said “ GROUP BY trunc(a.date, 'MM'), u.id;”

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
    SELECT
        T1.ID AS USER_ID,
        COUNT(T3.importFile_id) AS CNT,
        TO_CHAR(TRUNC(t3.date, 'MM'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS DATEE
    FROM USERR T1
    FULL JOIN ImportFile T2 ON T1.ID = T2. reportingUser_id
    FULL JOIN Activity T3 ON T3.importFile_id = T2. ID
    GROUP BY TRUNC(t3.date, 'MM'), T1.ID )
ORDER BY USER_ID
```

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in comments, the original post was missing data in ImportFile table for User 2. Once that is fixed, you'll just need to modify your original query to have `count(distinct a.importfile_id)` and `group by trunc(a.date, 'MM'), user.id`

I've added a demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8f89264899216e5de42818fc40dd8df3)